# ReactCrop cropping image with original resolution instead of the changed using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The width of the image uploaded and displayed is changed by using `max-width:100%;` but ReactCrop crops the original image.
I tried changing the image width is automatically adjusted with container width but it the react-image-crop crosshair does not adjust to it and it crops the image on the basis of the previous resolution.
In the image I have attached, you can see that image the cropped section does not appear in the preview of the crop. What it shows is the crop preview of what it would have been for the original resolution.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactCrop from "react-image-crop";
import { Button } from "antd";
import "./custom-crop.scss";
import {
  image64toCanvasRef,
  extractImageFileExtensionFromBase64,
  base64StringtoFile,
  downloadBase64File
} from "./reusableUtils";

class ImageUploader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.imagePreviewCanvasRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      isVerified: false,
      imgSrc: null,
      imgSrcExt: null,
      crop: {
        aspect: 1 / 1,
        unit: "px", // default, can be 'px' or '%'
        x: 130,
        y: 50,
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      }
    };
  }

  onChange(e) {
    let currFile = e[0];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.addEventListener(
      "load",
      () => {
        this.setState({
          imgSrc: fileReader.result
        });
      },
      false
    );
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(currFile);
  }

  handleOnCropChange = crop => {
    this.setState({ crop: crop });
  };

  handleImageLoaded = () => {
    // console.log(image);
  };

  handleOnCropComplete = crop => {
    //console.log(crop, pixelCrop)

    const canvasRef = this.imagePreviewCanvasRef.current;
    const { imgSrc } = this.state;
    // const imageData64 = canvasRef.toDataURL("image/" + fileExtension);
    const fileExtension = extractImageFileExtensionFromBase64(imgSrc);
    const fileName = "profile_pic." + fileExtension;
    const myNewCrop = base64StringtoFile(imgSrc, fileName);
    this.setState({ imgSrcExt: myNewCrop });
    image64toCanvasRef(canvasRef, imgSrc, crop);
  };

  handleDownloadClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const canvasRef = this.imagePreviewCanvasRef.current;
    const { imgSrc } = this.state;
    const imageData64 = canvasRef.toDataURL("image/" + fileExtension);
    const fileExtension = extractImageFileExtensionFromBase64(imgSrc);
    const fileName = "profile_pic." + fileExtension;
    const myNewCrop = base64StringtoFile(imgSrc, fileName);
    this.setState({ imgSrcExt: myNewCrop });
    // download file
    downloadBase64File(imageData64, fileName);
  };

  handleUpload = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // const canvasRef = this.imagePreviewCanvasRef.current;
    // console.log("data:", this.state.imgSrcExt);
  };

  render() {
    let { imgSrc } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={e => this.onChange(e.target.files)}
          style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}
        />
        {imgSrc != null ? (
          <div>
            <div style={{ overflow: "scroll", maxHeight: "500px" }}>
              <ReactCrop
                src={imgSrc}
                crop={this.state.crop}
                onChange={this.handleOnCropChange}
                onImageLoaded={this.handleImageLoaded}
                onComplete={this.handleOnCropComplete}
              />
            </div>
            <br />
            <canvas ref={this.imagePreviewCanvasRef}></canvas>
            <br />
            <div
              style={{
                marginTop: "20px",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between"
              }}
            >
              <Button
                // key="submit"
                style={{ background: "black", color: "white" }}
                onClick={this.handleDownloadClick}
              >
                Download
              </Button>
              <Button
                key="submit"
                style={{ background: "black", color: "white" }}
                onClick={this.handleUpload}
              >
                Upload
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageUploader;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GfnS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use percentage instead of pixels.
Something like this.

```
 onCropChange={(crop, percentCrop) =>
                    this.setState({ crop: percentCrop })
                  }
```